# How to wait for the next user message? Telegram.Bot C#

Tags: c#, telegram

I want when someone sends the word feedback to my bot, the bot waits for the next message and forwards that message to me
I know the rest of the parts, I just want to wait for the user's next message or move

```
//Private
else if (Messages.Chat.Type == Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.ChatType.Private)
{
    if (Messages.Text == "feedback")
    {
         await SevenLightsBot.SendTextMessageAsync(ChatId, "Please send feedback");
         //wait for new usermessage
         await SevenLightsBot.ForwardMessageAsync("me", ChatId , /* new message id*/);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should simply save the state of your conversation somewhere like in a database, and then resume from there once you get an update.